# jsf application throwing java.awt.headlessexception on jboss

Tags: java, linux, jsf

I created jsf application on windows, It is working fine. I changed my working environment to linux. Now I clicked a fileupload control(rich faces) on my application, it is throwing application error

java.awt.headlessexception.

please help me. I am new to linux.

Thanks in advance

**Stack Trace**

2011-03-07 08:43:34,856 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] #{ServiceRequestProfilePM.addNewProfile}: java.awt.HeadlessException:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

javax.faces.FacesException: #{ServiceRequestProfilePM.addNewProfile}: java.awt.HeadlessException:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

```
   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)

   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)

   at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.broadcast(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1387)

   at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)

   at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)

   at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)

   at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)

   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)

   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)

   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)

   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)

   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)

   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)

   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)

   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

   at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)

   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)

   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)

   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)

   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)

   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.awt.HeadlessException:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

```
   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)

   at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)

   ... 37 more
```

Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

```
   at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)

   at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)

   at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)

   at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)

   at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1727)

   at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1804)

   at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1673)

   at javax.swing.JOptionPane.getWindowForComponent(JOptionPane.java:1614)

   at javax.swing.JFileChooser.createDialog(JFileChooser.java:762)

   at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showDialog(JFileChooser.java:714)

   at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(JFileChooser.java:626)

   at de.db.mepit.recruitment.presentation.ServiceRequestProfilePM.addNewProfile(ServiceRequestProfilePM.java:708)

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)

   at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)

   at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)

   at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/getting-a-headlessexception-no-x11-display-variable-was-set/5218891#5218891

Comment: You say the application is working fine on Windows. Have you tested with the server running on a separate Windows host from the web browser?

Answer (score -1):

Could you post a bit more of your stacktrace? Is the next line:

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

If so try to add `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to your JAVA_OPTS and restart your app server.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.
I have pasted the stack trace

Answer (score -1):

Two Steps Required:

1. Enable X11 Forwarding: USe Putty, create new session with following setting enabled `Connection > SSH > X11` check the checkbox `X11 forwarding`.
2. Install some XServer: Install XMing Server and keep it running during the session.

The GUI will be tunneled through XMing