# Unable to run Java GUI programs with Ubuntu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ubuntu, runtime-error

I am learning GUI in Java, and for that I have created a demo program:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameDemo extends Frame {

    public FrameDemo(){
        super("Frame Demo");
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new FrameDemo();    
    }
}
```

It was compiled successfully. But when I tried to execute the program, I found the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:437)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at FrameDemo.<init>(FrameDemo.java:4)
    at FrameDemo.main(FrameDemo.java:9)
```

I am using Xubuntu 10.10 and `java -version` gives:

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.5) (6b20-1.9.5-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What should I to do?

One more thing: It is the same sort of error I got when I tried to execute Dr. Java and HJSplit's jar file.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Ubuntu has the option to install a *headless Java* -- this means without graphics libraries.  This wasn't always the case, but I encountered this while trying to run a Java text editor on 10.10 the other day.  Run the following command to install a JDK that has these libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

EDIT: Actually, looking at my config, you might need the JRE.  If that's the case, run:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: Hey but this is working just fine on my friends pc as he is using ubuntu 10.10 with the same jdk i have installed.

Comment: Ok Kaleb this is now working fine but still one problem that previously whenever i type `java Fram` and hit tab then it completes the name of the class file but right now it is not doing so? And one more thing there is only one file in that folder.

Comment: In my case I needed `jdk` indeed, not `jre`. I installed openjdk-11, though.

Answer (score 10):

I stopped getting this exception when I installed `default-jdk` using `apt`. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr), and the problem appears to have been the result of having a "headless" Java installed. All I did was:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Comment: that installs openjdk-7-jre for me, which fixes it sweet

Answer (score 4):

In my case

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

was set (indirectly by a [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) configuration). I had to actively use

```
-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

to override this.

Answer (score 2):

I too had **OpenJDK** on my Ubuntu machine:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Replacing OpenJDK with the HotSpot VM works fine:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

*[How to install the JDK on Ubuntu (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux/14788889#14788889)*

Answer (score 0):

Check your X Window environment variables using the "env" command.

Comment: No such variable exists. as i tried env|grep XW but nothing was there

Comment: I didn't mean a variable called exactly XWindow.

Comment: Hey here is what the command: env|grep X shows:    `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=e09e4f1f12d93b7c37a0cab100000007-1300541756.556846-1851639608
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-vinit-90yAl9/database`

Comment: Try: env | grep -i display <br/>
It gave me: 
DISPLAY=:0.0
This should be the essential X-Window env var for non-headless-ness.

Comment: env|grep -i display gives: `DISPLAY=:0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use JFrame instead of Frame. And do not extend from JFrame. Just write a class that has a JFrame property named `gui`, which configures this JFrame with the available methods, because it is better style doing it like this. Extending here is wrong the use of OOP.

Comment: But can you say what the problem with this. why it is showing me error message. because it is running just fine in windows

Comment: Maybe just try to use an other JRE than IcedTea6

Comment: JFrame is built on top of Frame, so changing that wouldn't matter much. Also, whether or not extending (J)Frame wouldn't help anything in case of a HeadlessException.

Comment: Anyway it is better style not extending.

Answer (score 0):

Check what your environment variable DISPLAY's value is. Try running a simple X application from the command line. If it works, check DISPLAY's value for the right value.

You can experiment with different values of and environment variable on a per invocation basis by doing the following on the command line:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 <your-java-executable-here>
```

How are you calling your program?

Comment: Hey allen i tried to run `evince` from command line and it works just fine. but when i tried to run `DISPLAY=:0.0 java FrameDemo` then the same problem

Comment: Also try: export DISPLAY=<:0.0 or some other stuff> and then run your app(s).

Comment: AFAIK, evince is not Java-based, so that would not matter much in this discussion.

Comment: when i tried the command `export DISPLAY=<:0.0` it says: `bash: :0.0: No such file or directory`

Comment: DISPLAY must contain something like 'hostname:x.y' or ':x.y'. The '<' and the '>' were to indicate what was to be substituted. Also, @karolrvn, the exception here is caused by JVM not finding one or more of display, mouse, or keyboard when it needs them.

Comment: Make the JVM dump its environment variables so you can see what is happening. Get a map of these settings from java.lang.System.getProperties() and print them out.

Answer (score 0):

I would check with another Java implementation/vendor. Preferrably Oracle/Sun Java: http://www.java.com/en/ . The open-source implementations unfortunately differ in weird ways.

Comment: I am using the java implementation downloaded from oracle's site

Comment: But is it the "regular" Java or OpenJDK? Try the thing not called OpenJDK.

Answer (score -2):

This command worked for me.

`Sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk`
(Fedora)

```
Sudo apt-get install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Should work for Ubuntu.

Comment: `dnf` is for Fedora, not Ubuntu, so that's probably no proper answer.

Comment: It really depends on your basic knowledge of Linux distributions. I have been able to use Ubuntu commands to fix Fedora problems in the past, by just knowing the equivalent commands.Plus this answer just increases the scope of the issue raised since I faced the same thing with Fedora.