# Getting java.awt.HeadlessException on running JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperPrint) method

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm getting the error with this code running on *Ubuntu 11*:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("/resources/etiquetas/etiquetaEndereco.jrxml");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros);
JasperViewer.viewReport(print);
```

Stack:

```
GRAVE: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.<init>(JasperViewer.java:264)
```

I don't find solution for this error.

Comment: Looks like you havea headless installation of Java. Which version are you using?

Comment: What operating system do you use, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu 11. This topic i think solution. Thank you. go test.

Answer (score 2):

As Java documentation shows, `java.awt.HeadlessException` is:

> Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is
>   called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or
>   mouse.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/HeadlessException.html))

and, for `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment`:

> The `GraphicsEnvironment` class describes the collection of
>   `GraphicsDevice` objects and `Font` objects available to a Java(tm)
>   application on a particular platform.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html))

Check if your report source file (`etiquetaEndereco.jrxml`) is calling fonts that could not be installed on your system.