# Another X11 Display Variable Linux issue

Tags: linux, debian, x11, vps

I'm trying to run a server that has an inbuilt gui on startup of the source. I could work out how to take it out however I want to try and sort it out anyway; here's my error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
            at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
            at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
            at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
            at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
            at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
            at server.model.controlpanel.ControlPanel.<init>(ControlPanel.java:20)
            at server.Server.<clinit>(Server.java:69)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must leave the GUI code in your server, then you can use [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) to provide a virtual X server, and set `DISPLAY` to point to that. But really, the best answer is to modify the code so it doesn't try to display a GUI.

Comment: When I run the source on windows the Gui doesn't come up, as it's turned off by default. I have no idea why it tries to open on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

funnily enough, your code fails because of missing X11 when checking whether it can use X11...

i strongly suspect that your installed java version does not have headless (no-X11) support.

you might want to check out [Unable to run java gui programs with ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu)