# Can't run Weka explorer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, linux, exception, jar, weka

I've read that there are only two steps needed to run Weka on linux, that is:

1. Add weka directory to CLASSPATH
2. Run `java -jar weka.jar`

After running above command I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:218)
    at weka.gui.LogWindow.<init>(LogWindow.java:252)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<clinit>(GUIChooser.java:215)
```

Does anyone have any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5362572/2865997

Comment: It was! I was using oracle's jdk and running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` solved my problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks so much.  This solved my issue when installing JOSM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using oracle's jdk and running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` solved my problem.