# running WEKA on Linux

Tags: java, linux, weka

I am  trying to run weka on linux server.
The steps I followed as listed below:
1. I download a zipped archive containing Weka as given on http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

2. I then unzipped the zip file.
3. I next tried executing weka.jar using the command:

   **java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar weka.jar**

I also simply tried: **java -jar weka.jar**
This also gives me errors.

I have set the DISPLAY variable using setenv DISPLAY localhost:0.0. 
I have tried other values too such as DISPLAY 0

weka.jar has also been added to the PATH variable.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
   at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
   at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:433)
   at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
   at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:202)
   at weka.gui.LogWindow.<init>(LogWindow.java:252)
   at weka.gui.GUIChooser.<clinit>(GUIChooser.java:215)
Could not find the main class: weka.gui.GUIChooser. Program will exit.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried researching a bit? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277062/cant-run-weka-explorer-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: The solution listed their involves sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre. I cannot do that.

Comment: Any other way you think it can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to add the CLASSPATH. For example:

```
java -cp "$CLASSPATH:./weka.jar" -Xmx500m weka.gui.explorer.Explorer
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Caused%20by:%20java.awt.HeadlessException&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=xi6QVPGaItftaIXdgUg) told me to run this command :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Comment: I am trying to set up weka in my local space on a server. Therefore, I do not have sudo rights.

Answer (score 0):

When I did as following, it worked.

- 1. Extract weka.jar to directoy named weka.
- 2. Write a script runWeka.sh:

> ```
> #! /bin/bash
> WEKA_HOME="~/weka";
> java -classpath $WEKA_HOME weka.gui.Main
> ```

- 3. Run this script.