# Running Java GUI apps on Cloud 9

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to run a simple app that just creates a `JFrame` and displays it through the web IDE Cloud 9. I'm getting two separate errors

1. Exception in thread "main" `java.awt.HeadlessException:`
   No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

   When this issue is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu) I then get this error:
2. Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:`

Is it possible to run GUI programs through cloud 9? Does anyone know how to update the path variable/java version on cloud 9?

Comment: What is the point of launching a frame on the server?  If you want the frame on the client computer, deploy it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: This is what i was looking for, can you deploy web start on anything but a tomcat server?

Comment: *"..can you deploy web start on anything but a tomcat server?"*  From any server that will serve files to the internet.

Comment: I wish. Cloud 9 is geared for making web applications, not desktop though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to run GUI programs on Cloud9.