# No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it using Putty?

Tags: linux, x11, putty, display

I am using Putty to connect to a Server that was running remotely  .
To monitor the server i entered jconsole under the putty terminal

I was getting this below exception .

```
[user001@test.hhh.com ~]$  jconsole
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:202)
        at sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole.<init>(JConsole.java:97)
        at sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole$6.run(JConsole.java:770)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
[user001@test.hhh.com ~]$
```

Even though i tried changing the Putty Setting following theis site .

[Getting a HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/getting-a-headlessexception-no-x11-display-variable-was-set)

But still i am getting the same Exception again and again , could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Comment: Or use some console monitoring programs like `top` or `htop`

Answer (score -1):

Install an X server on your local machine, and enable X forwarding as given in the other question.